# SpringBoot MDC only for the next log

Tags: spring-boot, mdc

Small question regarding SpringBoot application, and MDC logs please.

I have a very simple SpringBoot web handler:

```
  @GetMapping(path = "/mdcOnlyToThisLogPlease")
    public Mono<String> mdcOnlyToThisLogPlease(@RequestBody Book book) {
        MDC.setContextMap(Map.of("bookName", book.getTitle(), "bookAuthor", book.getAuthor()));
        LOGGER.info("I would like to have a log with bookName and bookValue as first level key for the MDC Json log, and only for this log please");
        return bookService.doSomething(book.getTitle(), book.getAuthor());
    }
```

Here, I would like to log as first level keys in the json the title and author of the book, I would like to get this:

```
{ 
    @timestamp:  2022-02-22T02:22:22.222Z 
    @version:  1 
    bookName: someName
    bookAuthor: someAuthor
    level:  INFO 
    level_value:  20000 
    logger_name:  MyClass 
    message: I would like to have a log with bookName and bookValue as first level key for the MDC Json log, and only for this log please
    spanId:  e58ad767e34525de 
    thread_name:  reactor-http-epoll-1 
    traceId:  ccf32f0b5d210aa2 
}
```

And I thought this piece of code would do just that.
Unfortunately, it is also logging the keys, for each and every logs that comes after!

For instance, I see also in the logs from bookService.doSomething(), health check logs, and many more...

```
{
    @timestamp:  2022-05-02T04:31:30.648Z 
    @version:  1 
    bookName: someName
    bookAuthor: someAuthor
    level:  INFO 
    level_value:  20000 
    logger_name:  reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog 
    message:  0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 - - [02/May/2022:04:31:30 +0000] "GET /health/readiness HTTP/2.0" 200 5088 19 
    thread_name:  reactor-http-epoll-1 
}

{
    @timestamp:  2022-05-02T04:33:30.648Z 
    @version:  1 
    bookName: someName
    bookAuthor: someAuthor
    level:  INFO 
    level_value:  20000 
    logger_name:  bookService 
    message:  Log from book service. I do not wish to see bookName and bookAuthor as keys
    thread_name:  reactor-http-epoll-1 
}

{ 
    @timestamp:  2022-05-02T04:40:48.742Z 
    @version:  1 
    bookName: someName
    bookAuthor: someAuthor
    level:  INFO 
    level_value:  20000 
    logger_name:  reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog 
    message:  0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 - - [02/May/2022:04:40:48 +0000] "GET /health/liveness HTTP/2.0" 200 5088 25 
    thread_name:  reactor-http-epoll-1 
}
```

May I ask how to add the keys, but only for the next / the one log please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the SLF4J MDC-

For a **single** key-value pair at a time, the MDC comes with `MDCCloseable`, which allows you to take advantage of the try-with-resources block:

```
log.info("This will be logged without myKey, myValue");
try (MDC.MDCCloseable ignored = MDC.putCloseable("myKey", "myValue")) {
    log.info("This will be logged with myKey, myValue");
}
log.info("This will be logged without myKey, myValue");
```

In this form, the entry you put in `MDC.putCloseable(...)` will be removed automatically at the end of the block. See the [Javadocs](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/MDC.html#putCloseable-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Unfortunately, there is no similarly convenient method for doing **multiple** entries at once. It's possible to nest multiple try-with-resources/`MDC.putCloseable()` blocks, but doing so can make the code messy.

Luckily, it isn't too hard to write your own, just implement `Closeable` and keep track of the keys you enter into the MDC:

```
// MDCCloseableMap.java
public class MDCCloseableMap implements Closeable {
    private final Set<String> keys;

    public MDCCloseableMap(Map<String, String> entries) {
        this.keys = Collections.unmodifiableSet(entries.keySet());
        entries.forEach(MDC::put);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        keys.forEach(MDC::remove);
    }
}
```

Which you can then use in the same way:

```
log.info("This will be logged without myKeys, myValues");
Map<String, String> myEntries = Map.of("myKey1", "myValue1", "myKey2", "myValue2");
try (MDCCloseableMap ignored = new MDCCloseableMap(myEntries)) {
    log.info("This will be logged with myKeys, myValues");
}
log.info("This will be logged without myKeys, myValues");
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Upvote + accept